# Is it appropriate here to use "of" or not here?

Tags: prepositions, possessives

Which is correct?

a) There is no consensus about the definition of chronic brain damage.
b) There is no consensus about chronic brain damage definition.

How many words could be placed in a row without using "of"?

Comment: It's not how many words can be placed in a row without using "of", it's which words. We say "the definition of art" (for example) and not "art definition" (just two words). But "chronic brain damage treatment" (four words) would be fine.

Comment: Depends how badly you want to write. As a rule of thumb, the more, the worse your style. What have you against prepositions, anyway? They are not generally regarded as obscene.

Comment: Thanks  @David and Peter I think it is better for me to use prepositions since I am not aware about the rule of possessions

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The sentence a) is much easier to understand as it is written in a more typical, commonly used English style.